# Integral domain of prime characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $x$ and $y$ belong to an integral domain of prime characteristic $p$. How  can I prove that

$$(x+y)^{p^n} = x^{p^n} + y^{p^n}$$

for all positive integers $n$? Please help.

Comment: Binomial theorem.

Comment: Hint: You only really need to prove it for $n=1$. The rest follows easily by induction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by demonstrating that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$. You can do this by writing

$$(x+y)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}x^ky^{p-k}$$

and showing that $p \mid \binom{p}{k}$ unless $k=0,p$. Then the result follows by induction.